# error in running android application project API-19.

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am new to android.
my application is not running.
i had my application running on android API-19 until i downloaded android API-21.

the error is with appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml

```
<!-- Action Button Styles -->

<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"  
       parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton">  //error
</style>
```

error#1
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 75 Android AAPT Problem

error#2
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\divX G\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'  DDUBusMarg      Build path  Build Path Problem

error#3
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    DDUBusMarg      Unknown Java Problem

error#4
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.   DDUBusMarg      line 1  Android ADT Problem

i deleted the android API-20 AND API-21. my target and compile SDK is API-19
i tried deleting the values-v21 folder(i checked this solution on different post) but it din't help. 
i am not able to resolve these errors. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem today.

I reimported the android-support-v7-appcompat project downloading again the full sdk bundle.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

The folder you need to reimport is:

`bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`

EDIT: you don't need to install the sdk again, you just need this files, not the ones that you downloaded by the SDK Manager